# Should volatile be used with a (non-concurrent) collection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, locking, volatile

I'm familiar with the basic idea of `volatile` (to prevent compiler optimization of instructions involving values that may be accessed from multiple threads, in summary), but I've noticed that examples I've found involving `volatile` and .NET 3.5 collections (NOT .NET 4 `Concurrent` collections. I know what they are but my current context does not allow me to use .NET 4.) never have `volatile` applied to the collection itself. Of course the collection (or a corresponding locking `object`) will need to be locked when accessing it from multiple threads, but is there a reason that a collection should not be marked `volatile`? Is the type of collection significant (i.e. a `List` of value types versus a `List` of reference types)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Volatile almost certainly doesn't mean what you think it does.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx) That's the main reason for not using it. (These days I refuse to try to describe what volatile means. It's too complicated to explain neatly, and it's almost always the wrong approach unless you're a memory model expert, in which case you definitely don't need *me* to explain it to you.)

If you're locking on an appropriate object, what benefit do you believe it will give you? You're already going to be going through appropriate memory fences in acquiring and releasing the lock... I suspect any reasons for using `volatile` for the variable itself are based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: Now that you mention it, my desire to use volatile is based almost entirely on anecdotal accounts of needing both volatile and lock to get effective multithreading behavior, which is not a good reason.

Comment: @Kongress: Don't trust anything you read on `volatile` or multithreading unless it comes from a very, very, very reputable source. Even most books get it wrong.

Comment: @Jason Fair enough. I've always been pretty leery of it such that I use dedicated locking objects when I'm not sure, although generally I figure it can't hurt to throw it (volatile) in there to be safe. Should I stop doing that entirely and just stick with locking?

Comment: @Kongress: Yes. Or use lock-free building blocks built by people who really know their stuff.

Comment: This link you posted is awesome! Even someone brain-dead like myself can understand!

Comment: @Kongress: Yes, if you don't understand, stop. As Jon hints at, there are other concurrent collections out there (in addition to the ones that come in .NET 4.0 that you mention you can't use currently). Use those if you can.

Comment: @Tipx: Of course it's awesome - it's Eric Lippert. But read it carefully: "The true semantics of volatile reads and writes are considerably more complex than I've outlined here."

Comment: @Jon hehe, yes. I've read the article, but I don't consider I know anything about the subject. I just think I understand the problematic a little, and I understood why some of the approaches to solve it are wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you are actually changing the reference for the collection (i.e., repeatedly assigning a new collection to a variable referring to a collection) there is no reason to mark that variable as `volatile` (that is, it is not doing what you think it does).

Even if you are (and then I will question what you are doing???), it's not clear that you would need `volatile` if you are `lock`ing properly.

By the way, this subject is really hard. really, Really, REALLY hard.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't changing the *reference* (i.e. creating an entire new unrelated collection and replacing that in the field), then `volatile` will do nothing. Personally, I'd probably make the collection field `readonly` in thread-intensive cases  *just to prevent accidents* (and use `lock`).

So probably: no.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a lock. There's no call for `volatile` in what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

If you mark collection by volatile you just mark reference itself, not a whole collection.